# Quick help on how to format a logic statement

Tags: django, django-models

this might seem silly, but i need help,
I have a model, in which if "is_vendor" is True, I want it to display something, while if "is_vendor" is False, I dont want the item to display. I already figured how to switch the is_vendor from True to False or vice versa, What i want now is to know how to complete `{% if user_profile.is vendor...` statement (Plus Im not sure if want i typed there is close to correct. Thank you

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bio = models.CharField(max_length=245, null=True)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My template:

```
 **{% if user_profile.is_vendor** 
            <div style="margin-left: 40px">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mb-4 mr-3 "href="{% url 'vendor_register' %}">
                    Register
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: `{% if user.profile.is_vendor %} ... {% endif %}`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out and get back to you. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if user_profile.isVendor %}
         <div style="margin-left: 40px">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mb-4 mr-3 "href="{% url 'vendor_register' %}">
                    Register
                </a>
            </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

{% if user_profile.isVendor %}

your code in here

{%endif %}

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in, you can access that user with `{{ user }}`. Since you have a `OneToOneField` to the `Profile` model, you thus can access the `Profile` record of the logged in user with `{{ user.profile }}`, and thus check if it is a vendor with `{{ user.profile.is_vendor }}`, we thus can wrap this in an [**`{% if … %} … {% endif %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if):

```
{% if user.profile.is_vendor %}
    …
{% endif %}
```